# TestFlight builds and ITC analytics

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Should iTunes Connect Analytics show data for TestFlight beta builds? I thought it should, but my most recent 2 builds don't appear in ITC analytics (nor do they show up in Google Analytics).

The new builds have a new version number. That version is nowhere to be found in the analytics screens, even after a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned it was never mentioned that App Analytics is also available for TestFlight builds. If you head over to the official docs, they are only talking about App Store users and people actually downloading/buying your app via the App Store.

> **Why can't I see my app in App Analytics?**
>   An app needs to have at least one approved version to appear in App Analytics. Deleted apps won't appear in the apps list.
>   [Quote Source](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Analytics_Overview)

http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc14b94d665
http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc21781223f